# A proof of Edelstein and Kelly theorem

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology

Edelstein and Kelly theorem states the following.

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be $3$ nonempty finite subsets of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that affine-span $(A \cup B \cup C)$ has dimension at least $4$ and 
$A \cap B \cap C$ is empty. Then there exists a line intersecting exactly $2$ of the sets $A$, $B$, $C$.

Where can I find a proof of this theorem? I can not find the corresponding paper

[ M. Edelstein and L. M. Kelly. Bisecants of ﬁnite collections of sets in linear spaces.
*Canadanian Journal of Mathematics*, 18:375–380, 1966 ].

Comment: https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v18/cjm1966v18.0375-0380.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to Victor:
cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v18/cjm1966v18.0375-0380.pdf